# Audio file in .m4a format which is not getting played in audioplayers using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an audio file in a .m4a file format which I want to play in [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) package in my Flutter chat app. So is there any solution for audioplayers or any other player in a flutter that supports .m4a files or do I need to convert the m4a file to any other format?

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score -1):

Play Music (mp3, m4a etc) from Google Drive using this package.

Audio Package: https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio

After getting the **Google Drive URL**, It might look something like:
`https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXhIg5iTGwYrl9_pEPmXEJieoi_i9w9y/view?usp=sharing`

Find the `<FILE_ID>` from Google Drive URL.

In my case the `<FILE_ID>` is `1oXhIg5iTGwYrl9_pEPmXEJieoi_i9w9y`. Its the ending portion after d/ or sometimes there is `id=` make sure to work according to your case.

Concatenate it with the link
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id= `<FILE_ID>`

After concatenate this link look this:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1oXhIg5iTGwYrl9_pEPmXEJieoi_i9w9y`

More details here: https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/o1htzt/using_google_drive/?rdt=50130

Comment: Ops ask for using audioplayers, just_audio not maintained a long time ago